# Intellij IDEA could't generate hibernate.reveng.xml?

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea

My teacher teaches us using Netbeans to study Hibernate.
But I I'm love in Intellij IDEA.
When I Generate Presistence Mapping, I could not generate hibernate.reveng.xml
I don't know if hibernate.reveng.xml is essential in Hibernate programming(because some times it exactly can work, but usually failed)

It's my first question in Stackoverflow. Help me please.

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://XXXX:3306/stuinfo</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">XXXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="resources.DaibanAccountEntity"/>
        <mapping class="resources.DaibanInformEntity"/>
        <mapping class="resources.OperatelogEntity"/>
        <mapping class="resources.UploadfileEntity"/>
        <mapping class="resources.XueshengInfoEntity"/>


        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

ERROR MESSAGE:

hql> from DaibanAccountEntity
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21] org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [resources.DaibanInformEntity]
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : resources.DaibanInformEntity
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:104)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at com.intellij.hibernate.console52.remote.HibernateFacadeImpl$MyRemoteConfigurationImpl.buildSessionFactory(HibernateFacadeImpl.java:36)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    [2016-11-26 17:13:21]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Seems Intellj still doesn't support hibernate.reveng.xml. Please see this ticket for more information.https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203925810-Hibernate-reveng-xml